# Start a batch once the other closes. Windows CMD .bat file

Tags: batch-file

I have 16 batch files

1.bat
2.bat
3.bat
...
16.bat

I will one batch file run 1.bat when 1.bat closed open 2.bat and ...

Thank you.

Comment: See `call /?` for help.

Comment: How use call? please explain

Comment: http://ss64.com/nt/call.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a `runbat.bat` :

```
@echo off
for /l %%a in (1 1 16) do (
  call "%%a.bat"
)
echo Done !!!
pause
```